# Is there a canonical question for a common misuse of `or` in Python?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Every few days, I see one or two questions like this:

> Why is "bad answer" never printed?
>
> ```
> answer = input("Yes or No").lower()
> if "yes" or "no" in answer:
>     print("good answer")
> else:
>     print("bad answer")
> ```

The point I'm raising here is the misuse of `or` in the condition test. Variants also include

```
value == "this" or "that
value == ("this" or "that")
a or b is True
(answer_1 or answer_2) == "good"
```

Although some of them have different results from others (always true vs. always false), they're caused by the same problem.

Is there a canonical question as a dupe source for these examples to be closed?

Comment: https://sopython.com/canon/22/why-doesn-t-if-x-a-or-b-or-c-do-what-i-expect/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just checked that site before I ask this question, but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Questions involving testing multiple variables against a single value have a couple of options:

1. [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) - This is the defacto option (quick google for "multiple variables single value")
2. If they still don't get it, there's also [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. Lastly, there's [Multiple 'or' condition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304500/multiple-or-condition-in-python) which is basically rehashing everything from the first two.

Usually the first is sufficient, but it sometimes helps OP to mark questions as dupes of multiple posts.

Comment: I think I closed those questions with that very dupe at least 50 times.